# I got a NullPointerException error when i was runing junit with RobolectricTestRunner on Android Studio

Tags: robolectric

I got a NullPointerException error when i was runing junit with RobolectricTestRunner on Android Studio

i checked test_config.properties file.

```
#Generated by the Android Gradle plugin
android_custom_package=com.zdc.navigation
android_merged_assets=build\intermediates\merged_assets\arm8Debug\out
android_merged_manifest=build\intermediates\merged_manifests\arm8Debug\AndroidManifest.xml
android_resource_apk=build\intermediates\apk_for_local_test\arm8DebugUnitTest\apk-for-local-test.ap_
```

android_merged_resources is not included in properties
but android_resource_apk is included.

i am setting following property in build.gradle, grade.properties.

```
testOptions {
unitTests {
includeAndroidResources true
}
}
```

```
android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=false
```

thanks you.

Robolectric 3.8
gradle plugin 4.0.1
gradle 6.1.1
Android Studio 4.0.1
Android SDK 27

Answer (score -1):

i resolved this issue by myself.
down version of gradle plugin to 3.1.2